# How can I include the C++ Actor Framework in an Xcode Project?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++-actor-framework

I followed the instructions [here](https://actor-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FirstSteps.html) and the tests passed but I'm unsure of which files I need to add to my `Xcode` project.  I have the following:

[image]

`libcaf_core/caf` has a bunch of `hpp` files such as `all.hpp`

But the `build/lib` folder has some `dylib` files:

[image]

Can anybody tell me how to add CAF to an existing project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed [CAF](https://github.com/actor-framework) with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) then set the `header` and `library` paths:

`headerPath="/usr/local/include"`

and:

`libraryPath="/usr/local/lib"`

I then added the `dylib` files:

`libcaf_core.0.15.3`
`libcaf_io.0.15.3`